# How to typecheck a value before asignment?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have to pass a string to the `name` prop of a React component.

For example:

```
<Column name="address" />
```

The `name` prop accepts any string, but I would like to limit it to a specific type, for example:

```
type ColumnNames = "address" | "phone"
```

So, I would like that Typescript verifies that the string I pass to the `name` prop is either "address" or "phone".

My current hack to do this is to define a dummy function only to typecheck the arguments:

```
const typecheckColumnNames = (value: ColumnNames) => value
```

Then, to pass a string to the `name` prop, I would do something like this:

```
<Column name={typecheckColumnNames("address")} /> // OK

<Column name={typecheckColumnNames("hello")} /> // type error: "hello" is not "address" nor "phone"
```

But this approach has the disadvantage of the runtime overhead of the function and the visual noise.

So, has Typescript any built-in feature to do this?

Comment: Can you not just define the prop types for the Column component?

Comment: "disadvantage of the runtime overhead "  you know typescript has absolutely no runtime impact right? It compiles to plain javascript after verifying all the types.

Comment: he's right cause the function is still there at runtime

Comment: @jonrsharpe The Column component is from a third party library, so to modify the prop types I would have to wrap that component with a custom one

Comment: Well that's easy enough to do, no? Then you don't need to remember the function everywhere the component's used, and you have a facade protecting your own code from the third party library's changes.

Comment: I will consider to change the type of the prop (as @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen showed in his answer) as an alternative approach to defining a dummy function, but I still find it a bit hacky and verbose. I would prefer if something like this be possible:

<Column name={"address" oftype ColumnNames} />

and that Typescript verifies that "address" is of type ColumnNames.

Comment: well if you needed to guarantee it is used correctly then maybe consider using an `enum` to store viable values, `Column` doesn't have to verify anything for you you just use the convention in your code that column names must always be specified as an enum member. (and passing around a column name as a variable lets you use the strict enum type).  This still doesn't stop you from doing `<Column name="HAHAHA"/>`, the only way to do that is to redefine `Column`.

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen Thank you, I will consider that approach too. Still, defining an `enum` has some runtime overhead, as defining a dummy function

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen On the other hand, in real code situations, the type `ColumnNames` actually comes from other types, for example using the `keyof` keyword, so defining an `enum` with the same fields would not be DRY

Comment: [a `const enum` has no runtime impact](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=7&ssc=31&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgYRAGxWAcgQ2TghgG8BYAKBhpnwBN6AnYkgXhgCIHnXOAaKrRgAHABbg4MDp3GTOVAL5UVlUJFj5p6LDgJEIAOh4sIEANxA). Are you actually trying to limit the name of a column in your code or is this a simplified example of what you are actually doing? I can think of alternate solutions but it seems silly to apply such strict typing to what I assume is a text label.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the `const enum`. What I'm actually doing is populating a table with several columns. I'm using a UI library, which has a `<Table />` component (with a `data` prop) and a `<Column />` component (with a `name` prop). Then to populate the table I have to pass a list of objects to the `data` prop, and the objects must have the same keys as the strings I've passed to the `name` prop of the `<Column />` component.

Comment: What I would like is that Typescript verifies that the keys of the objects I pass to the `data` prop of the `<Table />` component match the values of the strings I passed to the `name` prop of the `<Column />` component. This way, nobody would accidentally change the string passed to the `name` prop, without causing a type error.

Answer (score 0):

to modify the prop types of a library component you can re-export it with modified props:

```
import {Column as _Column} from "YOUR_LIBRARY";

interface FixedProps extends React.ComponentProps<typeof _Column> {
    name: "phone" | "address"
}
export const Column: React.ComponentType<FixedProps> = _Column as any;
```